# Anacron wants to use sendmail. Why?

Tags: mail, anacron

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 and have added a short script to anacrontab. Now I get this log warning from Anacron:

> Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output

I use the default Postfix for mail rather than sendmail and I receive messages from other utilities (printer jobs, usb connected etc) via the usual Gnome messages. Why is Anacron insisting on sendmail, and do I have to install sendmail just for Anacron?

Comment: What mail-type commands does your script use?

Comment: None whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

`sendmail` is a generic command. As sendmail was an extremely common and widely used MTA, many scripts made previously assume sendmail is installed if e-mail is used.

This has forced other MTA's to emulate parts of sendmails behaviour.

If you have a look at [postfix' file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/postfix/filelist) you will see that it provides `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

You do not have to install the `sendmail` MTA, but installing `postfix` with `sudo apt install postfix` will provide you with the sendmail command that emulates the behavior of the original `sendmail`'s `sendmail` command.

Comment: But why do I need to instal an MTA just for Anacron? Why doesn't it report like the printer, usb port etc?

Comment: You don't *need* to install it. But without the `sendmail` command it will not send e-mails with the result. Traditionally `cron` sends the output of commands to the user owning the job. Anacron will work fine without it.

Comment: @vidario Thanks for your explanation. The script I am running just rsyncs two files and saves a list of installed packages. It has nothing to report if all goes well. When I run the script from the command line it just runs with no output. Anacrontab has three cronjobs already in it and until I added my job it never attempted to send mail. So I don't really understand what Anacron wants to email.

Comment: It warns you that it won't due to the missing `sendmail`. If you don't need that functionality, the warning doesn't apply to you. Ignore it. It's simply a standard message.

Comment: @vidario I'm sorry if I am being obtuse, but if it hasn't attempted to send any messages before, with the three cronjobs, why has it started trying to send email now?

Comment: Probably because some job produced some output.

Comment: @StevenInBavaria I'd recommend to install an MTA, because at some point the anacron job might fail, and you will never know about that if anacron can not send you emails. If you do not want to install a full blown postfix, consider installing nullmailer. that is an MTA that only forwards everything to another mailserver via SMTP, much smaller and simpler to configure

Comment: But sendmail *isn't* missing.  Postfix installs a /usr/bin/sendmail, it's anacron that somehow appears to be confused.